# Message data collecting architecture in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

At the time I build a messaging system with one on one dialog feature, and I've faced with the problem of storing message data. I've been thinking a lot about the most proper way. 
As far as I'm using PostgreSQL it seems to me **that collecting data in associative arrays where messages are united by some parameter** (such as day, or week, or limit amount of messages) is the most efficient way for this database.
PostgreSQL has powerful tools for working with arrays and I feel that this way of storing such diverse data may work out.
|_____Dialog03.31.17     id(First user)     id(Second user)
|_________message id(n)
|____________Sender id
|____________Message Plot
|____________Sending time
|
|_________message id(n+1)
|____________Sender id
|____________Message Plot
|____________Sending time

I'd like to know if this kind of architecture is good and if it's not please explain why.

Comment: JSON looks like a better fit for hierarchical data then simply arrays

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the type is not a question, I'm more interested in structure. Anyway thanks

Comment: user ids and dialog (whatever that means) are attributes of message not the opposite. Yes data types are not the question and both arrays and json are bad choices.